# Getting "Segmentation fault Core Dumped Error " while reversing a string

Tags: c, string, algorithm, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am trying to learn C, I am getting this error while reversing a string.  I am not well versed with memory allocation stuffs, can you please point out where I am doing wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* strrev(char *str);
int main()
{
  char str[1000];
  char *str1;
  printf("Please enter a String\n");
  gets(str);

  str1=strrev(str);
  puts(str1);

}

char* strrev(char *str)
{
  char *str1;
  int i,length,c;
  length=strlen(str);

  for (i=length-1;i<=0;i--)
  {
     *(str1+c) = *(str+i);
     c++;
  }
  *(str1+c) ='\0';
  return str1;

}
```

Comment: Using `gets` is discouraged because this function cannot prevent buffer overrun.

Comment: Your loop in `strrev` will never run for strings with a length of more than one characters. For zero-length string you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Unrelated to your errors, maybe just check all the other posts already on SO which does exactly the same thing, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673155/how-to-reverse-a-c-style-string-completely)?

Comment: Since you are just starting to learn c, now would be a good time to learn how to use GDB. It's a debugger that allows you to step through your code. It helps you learn the ins and outs of your code. It's simple and makes debugging errors like this a breeze. Here's a simple starter: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~srhuang/teaching/cmsc212/gdb-tutorial-handout.pdf

Comment: You're also not initializing c, which could be anything.  So you're writing to a random location in memory.

Comment: But we can directly assign a string value to a char type pointer. I mean char *ptr="witch" is completely acceptance then why do I have to assign memory in the above case. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not reversing a string. Neither string is reversed in your program. You are trying to copy one string in another string in the reverse order.

So the sring where you are going to copy the original string in the reverse order shall have enough space to store the copied characters.

However in your function

```
char* strrev(char *str)
{
  char *str1
  //...
```

pointer `str1` was not initialized and does not point to an extent of memory of the appropriate size.

So your program has undefined behaviour.

Take also in account that function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C standard any more. Use function `fgets` instead.

If your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays (VLA) then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse_copy( char *s2, const char *s1 )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s1 );
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) s2[i] = s1[n-i-1];

    s2[i] = '\0';

    return s2;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s1[1000];

    printf( "Please enter a String: " );
    fgets( s1, sizeof( s1 ), stdin );

    size_t n = strlen( s1 );

    if ( n != 0 && s1[n-1] == '\n' ) s1[n-1] = '\0';

    char s2[n + 1];

    puts( s1 );
    puts( reverse_copy( s2, s1 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter for example

```
Hello Asfakul Islam
```

then the output will look like

```
Please enter a String: Hello Asfakul Islam
Hello Asfakul Islam
malsI lukafsA olleH
```

Otherwise if your compiler does not support VLA(s) you need to dynamically allocate an array of the appropriate size. In this case the program can look for example the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse_copy( char *s2, const char *s1 )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s1 );
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) s2[i] = s1[n-i-1];

    s2[i] = '\0';

    return s2;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s1[1000];

    printf( "Please enter a String: " );
    fgets( s1, sizeof( s1 ), stdin );

    size_t n = strlen( s1 );

    if ( n != 0 && s1[n-1] == '\n' ) s1[n-1] = '\0';

    char *s2 = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char ) );

    puts( s1 );
    puts( reverse_copy( s2, s1 ) );

    free( s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not initialized? What do I need to to initialize a pointer? Should I just assign a value?

Comment: @AsfakulIslam You are using a pointer that has undetermined value. You need 1) to allocate memory where you are going to write the reversed string and 2) to assign the pointer by the address of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `strrev()` function, `str1` is not allocated memory. Hence, `*(str1+c) = *(str+i);` is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then, `c` is an automatic local variable which is not initialized before use. Also UB.

Next, [as Giorgi mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522387/2173917), correct your for loop.

That said, don't use `gets()`, it suffers from buffer overrun issues. Use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (i=length-1;i<=0;i--)
```

This will never (unless string is 0 or 1 character long) run due to `i<=0`, should be `i>=0` probably.

Also in general you need to make pointer point to some valid memory in order to be able to dereference it. In your case you should probably use `malloc` for allocating sufficient number of bytes, and assign its result to `str1`. Then you can write to it as you are doing.

Comment: Strictly speaking, not never. What if the length of string `str` is zero or one ?

Comment: @MikeCAT: Yes, incorporated

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you did not initialize `c`

```
int i,length,c;
```

and are using it inside the `for` loop

```
*(str1+c) = *(str+i);
```

Plus other problems are there..

1) `str1` inside the function is not allocated memory.

2) This loop will never get executed, as the condition in `for (i=length-1;i<=0;i--)` is never true (unless string is 0 or 1 character long).

3) Do not use `gets()`, it is deprecated. Instead use `fgets()`

Comment: `i<=0` do become true if `length<=1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't initialize `str1` in `strrev()`
2. If you enter string whose length is 2 characters or more, `i<=0` is false and the block inside the `for` loop won't be executed.
3. `*(str1+c) ='\0';` will cause the crash because the value of `str1` is indeterminate and you have few chance that `str1` points some valid place.

UPD: `c` in `strrev()` is also uninitialized, and it **will** cause some trouble.